R documentation not found with `devtools::load_all()`
I am developing an R package and use roxygen for creating package documentation.
Whenever I load the package via devtools::load_all() (after running devtools::document()) the package documentation does not work.
Specifically, when I type ?function_name I get the following error:
Error in .get_package_metadata(pkgdir) : 
Files 'DESCRIPTION' and 'DESCRIPTION.in' are missing.

However, when I install the package from command line and use library for loading it, the documentation works. In particular, the DESCRIPTION file exists and seems to be fine, and the documentation- and NAMESPACE-files seem to be created just fine by roxygen.
Since the issue seems to be related to the package setup: I am working on Windows 10 using R 4.4.1 in RStudio (version 2024.09). The package directory is on my harddrive, so nothing fancy there, and the package was set up using usethis::create().
Running traceback() on the error above yields
5: stop("Files 'DESCRIPTION' and 'DESCRIPTION.in' are missing.")
4: .get_package_metadata(pkgdir)
3: tools::loadPkgRdMacros(file.path(R.home("share"), "Rd", "macros", 
   "system.Rd"), macros = macros)
2: .rs.RdLoadMacros(file)
1: .rs.Rd2HTML("C:/<path-to-documentation-file>.Rd", "<package name>")


This might be a problem with an outdated version of RStudio, see here: https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/issues/1840. Are you running the newest versions of devtools and RStudio?
